# Morphing 3D objects in Blender

Tags: uv, modifiers, texture-baking

I'm thinking about morphing a frog into an octopus in an animation.
So I was thinking about modeling/sculpting the two animals, then baking them onto low poly meshes with vector displacement (especially baking the frog fingers onto a stump). From what I've read so far, this could work.

Then, once rigged, moving them into similar position and using some mesh deformer/corrector (like the [correctional PSD morph in C4D](https://youtu.be/gnTElmPVJAs?t=479)) to wrap the low poly octopus onto the low poly frog. Is there a similar deformer in Blender ?

The last thing I'd need to do is transferring the frog displacement and texture to the octopus to finally lower their "opacity" to 0 and crank up the octopus displacement and textures to 100 to finalise the morphing.

But since the octopus UVs should be quite different, how could I do that ?

I guess it's a quite complicated idea, lol. Thanks for the help.

Comment: yes, give your second object the same material, then in the UV/Image Editor, change its mesh position so that it fits the image texture, is it what you want? If not please give more details

Comment: Not sure if that would work since I'd like to make morphings. I'm thinking about morphing a frog into an octopus in an animation. So I was thinking about modeling/sculpting the two animals, then baking them onto low poly meshes with vector displacement (especially baking the frog fingers onto a stump). Then, once rigged, moving them into similar position and using some mesh deformer/correcter to wrap the low poly octopus onto the low poly frog. From what I've read so far, this could work.

Comment: The last thing I'd need to do is transferring the frog displacement and texture to the octopus to finally lower their opacity to 0 and crank up the octopus displacement and textures to 100 to finalise the morphing. But since the octopus UVs should be quite different would your suggestion work ? I guess it's a quite complicated idea, lol. Thanks for the help btw :)

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and clarify your question explaining in detail what you want to accomplish,

Comment: You don't necessarily have to change the UVs at all. You can just create two different shaders that use their own textures and UVs and animate the mix along with the geometric tranformation.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand here, do you mean to have the two animals displayed at the same time ? I think having one animal morphing to the other would give better results. If that's not what you mean I'd be glad if you could elaborate. Thanks!